# Marketpress php warning on server, no problem on localhost

Tags: array, localhost, warnings

I have this in my functions.php that creates a shopping cart widget with the plugin Marketpress.

```
<?php function marketpress_get_cart_subtotal($format_currency=true) {
    global $mp;

    $selected_cart = $mp->get_cart_contents(true);
    if (!$selected_cart) return;

    foreach ($selected_cart as $bid => $cart) {

        if (is_multisite())
            switch_to_blog($bid);

        foreach ($cart as $product_id => $variations) {
            foreach ($variations as $variation => $data) {
                $totals[] = $mp->before_tax_price($data['price'], $product_id) * $data['quantity'];
            }
        }

        //go back to original blog
        if (is_multisite())
            switch_to_blog($current_blog_id);

    }
    $total = array_sum($totals);
    if ($total > 0)
        return $mp->format_currency('', $total);
    else
        return '$0.00';
}
?>
```

This works fine locally on MAMP, but when I upload it to my server I get 
"Warning: array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
functions.php on line 255" instead of the cart total.

What is wrong with the code, and why is there a discrepency between the same file on my localhost and the online server?

Comment: This appears to be a **PHP** question, *not* a **WordPress** question. The error message is telling you that `$totals` is `null`, meaning it is not defined. Since `$totals` gets set when `$cart` has data as `$product_id => $variations`, the problem is likely either that you have no `$cart` defined, or `$cart` has no `$variations`. The solution is to wrap `$total` in an `if ( isset( $totals ) )` conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because of either different versions of PHP or different configuration for the Error logging. Assuming you have same environment (cart status, blog status, logged in user status etc)

To overcome this, Please initialize $totals with empty array in the start of the function.

And, If you want error to show up for localhost set WP_DEBUG constant to true (in wp-config.php) on localhost. You may also need to call `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of your script.

hope it will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was simple enough. And my apologies for posting a non-related question. I wasn't sure it was WP causing the errors or not!